# When one's look is the index of their mood

Tags: sentence-request

In my mother language, there is a proverb which says:
"It is absolutely easy to guess how one feels in which mood he /she is from their face / look / appearance." I have found three sentences in this regard in English; which one sounds more natural to you in AE:

> - The heart’s letter is read in the eyes.
> - The stuff the heart writes is read in the eyes.
> - The eyes are the mirror of the soul.

Comment: What ancient book of English poetry are you consulting? "The heart’s letter is read in the eyes" (from George Herbert, who died in 1633) was last seen in the wild in the 1890's. Such poetry is no longer deemed worthy of American students' attention, especially since they have Jay-Z's immortal _I can't see 'em comin down my eyes / So I gotta make the song cry_ to stand in its stead.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I didn't look for the resource of the sentences. These all might make you feel you are reading something like poems, but for us non-natives they sound another way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> face reading

is something practiced and understood by many cultures.

A saying which is similar to your native language proverb is

> I can see it in your face
>   You can see it in their faces

which encompasses looking at the entire face, not just the eyes.

The description

> poker face

means to show no emotion.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you are trying to express someone who makes their emotions/mood very obvious just from looking at them. The expression I am most familiar with would be

> She wears her heart on her sleeve

Answer (score 1):

I have only heard the last one:

> The eyes are the mirror of the soul.